# Two SELECTS return different counts, but all types of JOINS return same NUMBER of Rows, <> to either SELECT

Tags: sql, oracle, join, view, ssms

(Using SSMS v15 against a pair of Oracle v19 dbs)

SELECT against Table1 in new management system's db1 returns 312 depreciation trxns for the month.

SELECT against View1 in old management system's db2 returns 311 depreciation transactions for the month.

Discrepancies were expected between home-brewed system and new vended one, but finding them by eyeballing results from each result set is making my eyes hurt, and I have about 4500 rows of various types of transactions to validate...each of the next three months.

I would like JOINs to show me which ones on one side are missing on the other.
And these discrepancies might go both ways.

So I'd like a statement of LEFT JOIN, showing all 312 rows from first SELECT, and NULLS for the rows that are missing from the other.

AND I'd like a statement of RIGHT JOIN, showing the 311 rows from second SELECT, and NULLS for any rows missing from the other.

However, every JOIN returns 310 rows.

I have not been through all 310 to see if the same 310 have been returned for all four JOIN types, but it's 310 rows, every time.
Not a NULL row from either side.

Possibilities:
SQL Server Mgmt Studio not playing well with Oracle?
VIEW causing some side effects?
Operator error?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

```
select *  -- = 312 rows
from Database1.ACCT_EOM_TRANSACTIONS
where period_id = '092021'
and trans_type in ('DEPRECIATION', 'OTHER FIXED 3')
order by trans_type, eq_equip_no


select * -- = 311 rows
from Database2.V_FTS_SUM 
where bill_month = 9 and bill_year = 2021
and trans_type = 'DEPR'
order by trans_type, veh_ref_no

Select E.*, V.* 
from Database1.ACCT_EOM_TRANSACTIONS E
JOIN Database2.V_FTS_SUM V  --INNER, RIGHT OUTER, LEFT OUTER, JOIN = 310 rows
    ON E.eq_equip_no = V.veh_ref_no
where E.period_id = '092021'
and E.trans_type in ('DEPRECIATION', 'OTHER FIXED 3')
and V.bill_month = 9 and V.bill_year = 2021 
and V.trans_type = 'DEPR'
order by E.eq_equip_no
```

Comment: If an E row doesn't have a matching V row, an outer join will produce a row where all V columns are null. Then you say `where V.bill_month = 9` and that outer joined row will get dismissed, because its `bill_month` is null. You have turned your outer join into an inner join. An outer joined table's criteria must hence not be in the `WHERE` clause. With a left outer join we usually put it in the `ON` clause. With a full outer join, the criteria must even be put into subqueries. See Jon Armstrong's answer on how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Your `WHERE` clause was breaking the outer join behavior.

To find mismatches in both left and right side, use a `FULL [OUTER] JOIN`, like this:

```
WITH cte1 AS (
    select *  -- = 312 rows
      from ACCT_EOM_TRANSACTIONS
     where period_id = '092021'
       and trans_type in ('DEPRECIATION', 'OTHER FIXED 3')
     )
   , cte2 AS (
    select * -- = 311 rows
      from V_FTS_SUM 
     where bill_month = 9 and bill_year = 2021
       and trans_type = 'DEPR'
     )
SELECT *
  FROM cte1 FULL JOIN cte2
    ON cte1.eq_equip_no = cte2.veh_ref_no
 WHERE cte1.eq_equip_no IS NULL
    OR cte2.veh_ref_no  IS NULL
;
```

Fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4c68480cdfc5b9d06d5d70ade66235e3

Comment: Thanks to both of you, Jon for the script re-write/upgrade, and Thorsten for the explanation of why what I was doing wasn't working. 
This works (as you both already know). 
The 312 result has two missing on the other side, while the 311 has one missing, hence I always got 310 as a result, from either direction.
You have no idea how much time this will save me. 
StackOverflow again, for the win. Thanks.
(Bonus: never seen dbfiddle. Very cool.)

Comment: Now that I've worked with this, and handed the resulting 4 scripts off as tools to a partner in this analysis, I went back and re-read Thorsten's explanation, and 'got' the reason my script wasn't working. Jon's script is also much easier to manipulate for various analyses against the same comparison of rows. Points to both of you. Thanks again.